# Customization in Dynamics365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

Can we do customization in Dynamics365 portal up to such extent that we create a website with asp.net and java script which interact with Dynamics365 entities and open inside dynamics365 portal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will probably need to setup single sign on authentication between your website and the portal, the suggested manner of which is Azure AD B2C.

This is currently possible but undocumented, official support is coming soon.

This slide is from an executive briefing by Microsoft last week.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to host  It separately but some customization such that one section of Dynamic365 portal  opens my web application .Is this achievable?

Comment: Not if you want to use asp.net code, Microsoft Portal doesn't support it. You  could make a portal using the one time code drop instead but the code hasn't been dropped yet and you would also be unsupported

Comment: Can you please elaborate -:You could make a portal using the one time code drop instead but the code hasn't been dropped yet and you would also be unsupported

Comment: Adxstudio was procured by Microsoft. Adxstudio v7 allowed us to add custom asp.net controls into a portal - Adxstudio v7 is now pretty much deprecated. The new 'Microsoft Portal' (v8) doesnt allow the use of asp.net controls within the Microsoft hosted environment. Microsoft are releasing v8 as a one time open source drop, which you can add asp.net controls to. You will need to host and support the open source portal yourself.

Comment: Adding to @JamesWood comment: once you have this one-time drop, you'll be responsible for patches and upgrades. I personally consider this a bit of trap for the unwary by Microsoft as it will be difficult to keep your portal up-to-date. We have an online portal for one customer and we've noticed consistent releases and upgrades in the past couple of months; none of which will be available to your one-time drop.